# An Error! when trying to click a product in order to see its details - MEGENTO ONLINESTORE - cache_dir must be a directory Trace:

Tags: php, magento, csv, magmi

Say i'm looking for a car, i enter the "car" category, and then i see a Buick '97, when clicking on it to more details and purchase options, on some of the products it works just fine, but on others...:

There has been an error processing your request

```
cache_dir must be a directory

Trace:
#0 /home/oal4wi/domains/mysite.com/public_html/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php(154): Zend_Cache::throwException(\\\'cache_dir must ...\\\')
#1 /home/oal4wi/domains/mysite.com/public_html/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php(121): Zend_Cache_Backend_File->setCacheDir(\\\'tmp\\\')
#2 /home/oal4wi/domains/mysite.com/public_html/lib/Zend/Cache.php(153): Zend_Cache_Backend_File->__construct(Array)
#3 /home/oal4wi/domains/mysite.com/public_html/lib/Zend/Cache.php(94): Zend_Cache::_makeBackend(\\\'File\\\', Array, false, false)
#4 /home/oal4wi/domains/mysite.com/public_html/lib/Zend/Locale/Data.php(940): Zend_Cache::factory(\\\'Core\\\', \\\'File\\\', Array, Array)
#5 /home/oal4wi/domains/mysite.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Locale.php(633): Zend_Locale_Data::getContent(\\\'en_US\\\', \\\'currencynumber\\\')
#6 /home/oal4wi/domains/mysite.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View.php(158): Mage_Core_Model_Locale->getJsPriceFormat()
#7 /home/oal4wi/domains/mysite.com/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/MAG080116/template/catalog/product/view.phtml(83): Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View->getJsonConfig()
#8 /home/oal4wi/domains/mysite.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include(\\\'/home/oal4wi/do...\\\')
#9 /home/oal4wi/domains/mysite.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView(\\\'frontend/defaul...\\\')
#10 /home/oal4wi/domains/mysite.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#11 /home/oal4wi/domains/mysite.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#12 /home/oal4wi/domains/ymysite.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#13 /home/oal4wi/domains/mysite.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#14 /home/oal4wi/domains/mysite.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#15 /home/oal4wi/domains/mysite/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml(\\\'content\\\', true)
#16 /home/oal4wi/domains/mysite.com/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/MAG080116/template/page/2columns-right.phtml(59): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml(\\\'content\\\')
#17 /home/oal4wi/domains/mysite.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include(\\\'/home/oal4wi/do...\\\')
#18 /home/oal4wi/domains/mysite.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView(\\\'frontend/defaul...\\\')
#19 /home/oal4wi/domains/mysite.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#20 /home/oal4wi/domains/mysite.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#21 /home/oal4wi/domains/mysite.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(529): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#22 /home/oal4wi/domains/mysite.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(391): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#23 /home/oal4wi/domains/mysite.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(132): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#24 /home/oal4wi/domains/mysite.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), \\\'no-route\\\')
#25 /home/oal4wi/domains/mysite.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(75): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), \\\'no-route\\\')
#26 /home/oal4wi/domains/mysite.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(420): Mage_Cms_IndexController->noRouteAction()
#27 /home/oal4wi/domains/mysite.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch(\\\'noRoute\\\')
#28 /home/oal4wi/domains/mysite.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#29 /home/oal4wi/domains/mysite.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#30 /home/oal4wi/domains/mysite.com/public_html/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#31 /home/oal4wi/domains/electronics.mysite.com/public_html/index.php(80): Mage::run(\\\'electronics\\\', \\\'website\\\')
#32 {main}

Error log record number: 372472694932
```

PLS HELP ME OUT!
TNX IN ADVANCED!

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered on the Magento forums: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/17358/

"...make a tmp dir in the root of the magento installation..."

Answer (score 0):

Magento looks at some **$_ENV** and **$_SERVER** variables to find a reasonable writable directory. It looks for *TMPDIR*, *TEMP*, *TMP*, 
8windir*, and *SystemRoot* variables to find one. (You can see it in [Zend_Cache_Backend::getTmpDir](http://zendframeworkdocumentation.com/classZend__Cache__Backend.html#ad5a8e92e2751868024730d42094eed6a)).

So there are some steps to check...

1. Verify your apache/nginx user at phpinfo, and check if this user have rights to var/cache directory;
2. If you use apache and mod_env enabled, you can set your tmp dir manualy by adding the following line in your .htaccess:

> SetEnv TMP /path/to/other/tmp/dir

3 . If you use nginx, you can try to add a param like this:

> fastcgi_param TMP /path/to/other/tmp/dir